# Reactjs development setup

Tags: reactjs, development-environment

I have the following react html page contents, and I would like to know the problems with this style of react development. Mainly I do not use any bundling tools. I am a newbie and finds this very easy for development and integration with server side languages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="greeting-div"></div>

    <script src="react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="browser.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
    <script type="text/babel">

      class Greeting extends React.Component{
        render() {
          return (
            <p id="test">Hello, Universe</p>
          )
        }
      };

      ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting/>,
        document.getElementById('greeting-div')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are new I strongly recommend to check https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: I'd say this is ok for personal learning project. But wont scale if you start to add more components, external dependencies, collaborators or decide to make it production ready (bundling, minification, tests and such)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have hot reloading which is pretty awesome in React.

It will also scale awfully as you will have all your elements inside of the same html.

It will probably be bad to run a linter / any code analysis tool for it.

You should probably try create-react-app: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app, it's really simple to get started and you'll get a really good development setup.

Comment: can you explain your second and third points relative to the create-react-app method.

Comment: create-react-app already gets you started with a src directory where are located your react component so you can easily create new file to separate react components. It also includes a linter that will check for potentially problematic code.

Comment: regarding the react components in separate files, I can always have separate script tags that include jsx files and thus will have the same effects, right?

Comment: That's still one file. Also I don't know if it will properly handle variables.

Comment: you will pollute your global namespace, it will not be the same thing, when you use something like create-react-app, each component is isolated by a module bundler using AMD or commonJS, lets say you have two components or variables with the same name, doing things the way that you're doing one variable will override the other, its horrible do not do this, you will regret it, i can 100% assure you